# Iterating over table names and updating queries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm using PyMySQL to Update Data by iterating through table names , But the problem is that I was able to update the data from the first table only 
the loop is not working after the first table

Ive tried using the fetchall() to get the table names and loop by that but it didnt work

```
def update():
    global table_out
    global i
    cursor.execute("USE company;")
    cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES;")
    lst=[]
    for table_name in cursor:
         lst.append(table_name)
         emp_list=lst[0][0]
         print(emp_list)
         i=0
         while i<=len(lst)-1:
             state="""SELECT `employee_name` from `%s` WHERE attended=0 """%(employees)
             out=cursor.execute(state)
             result=cursor.fetchall()
             i+=1
             for records in result:
                 table_out=''.join(records)
                 print(table_out)
                 db.commit()
                 try:

                    sql="""UPDATE `%s` SET `attended` = True WHERE `employee_name` = '%s' ;"""%(emp_list,table_out)
                         cursor.execute(sql)
```

I expect to iterate over all the tables in that database when this function is called

Comment: You are updating the *cursor* variable inside the while loop ```out=cursor.execute(state)```, that is why the outer for loop that is iterating over cursor is not working after the first table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that your approach is quite optimal.

[In your middle block, `employees` is undefined - should that be emp_lst?]

Your select statement appears to reduce down to

```
SELECT employee_name FROM $TABLE WHERE attended=0;
```

which you then want to go through each table and change the value. Have you considered using the UPDATE verb instead? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE $table SET attended=True WHERE attended=0;
```

If that works for your desired outcome, then that will save you quite a few table scans and double handling.

So perhaps you could refactor your code along these lines:

```
def update_to_True():
# assume that cursor is a global
cursor.execute("USE company;")
tables = cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES;").fetchall()
for el in tables:
    STMT="""UPDATE {0} SET attended=True WHERE attended=0;".format(el)
    res = cursor.execute(el)
    # for debugging....
    print(res)
```

that's it!

Comment: Thank You james will check that out